# How to obtain default Apache getting-started.html?

Tags: apache, centos

I have simple problem, but for me it's difficult to resolve it.

I had standard `/var/www/html` directory but then I just delete it and I made virtual hosts but I didn't thought about copy default page (that `index.html`) but I need it back. Where I can find it or how to send "request" to Apache to generate it in folder in `/var/www/*`?

I am using CentOS7.

Comment: Have a look at the Apache source code, it's probably in there. Or, if this is a dev server, you could uninstall Apache and reinstall it, but be careful not to delete any of your own work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using CentOS, so presumably you're running Apache from the `httpd` package.  There is no content in `/var/www/html`:

```
[root@a02004d67c2b /]# cat /etc/centos-release
CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708 (Core) 
[root@a02004d67c2b /]# find /var/www/html/
/var/www/html/
```

The default welcome page is provided by `/etc/httpd/conf.d/welcome.conf`, which looks like:

```
<LocationMatch "^/+$">
    Options -Indexes
    ErrorDocument 403 /.noindex.html
</LocationMatch>

<Directory /usr/share/httpd/noindex>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

Alias /.noindex.html /usr/share/httpd/noindex/index.html
Alias /noindex/css/bootstrap.min.css /usr/share/httpd/noindex/css/bootstrap.min.css
Alias /noindex/css/open-sans.css /usr/share/httpd/noindex/css/open-sans.css
Alias /images/apache_pb.gif /usr/share/httpd/noindex/images/apache_pb.gif
Alias /images/poweredby.png /usr/share/httpd/noindex/images/poweredby.png
```

That means that if you do not have an `index.html` in your
`DocumentRoot` (i.e., `/var/www/html`), Apache will return a status
code 403 and the content from `/usr/share/httpd/noindex/index.html`.

You could reproduce the same configuration for your virtual host, or you could just copy the contents of `/usr/share/httpd/noindex` into your virtual host `DocumentRoot`.